# Guice - Multiple provider methods for same return types

Tags: java, guice

In my module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public ExecutorService provideExecutorService(){
    return new ExecutorService(config);
}
```

In my class:

```
@Inject
private ExecutorService executorService;
```

Now, I need two instances of ExecutorService with a different config:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public ExecutorService provideExecutorServiceA(){
    return new ExecutorService(configA);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public ExecutorService provideExecutorServiceB(){
    return new ExecutorService(configB);
}
```

If I want to inject ExecutorService for the one created with configB in my class, how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [binding annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Priority(Priority.Level.HIGH)
public static ReportingDal createHighPriorityReportingDal(DataSource dataSource,
                                                          DatabaseType databaseType,
                                                          ReportingQueryGenerator queryGenerator)
{
    return new ReportingDalImpl(dataSource, databaseType, Queue.DEFAULT, queryGenerator);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Priority(Priority.Level.LOW)
public static ReportingDal createLowPriorityReportingDal(DataSource dataSource,
                                                         DatabaseType databaseType,
                                                         ReportingQueryGenerator queryGenerator)
{
    return new ReportingDalImpl(dataSource, databaseType, Queue.MAINTENANCE, queryGenerator);
}
```

The @Priority annotation looks like this :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD })
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Priority
{
    Level value();

    public enum Level
    {
        LOW,
        HIGH
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't want to implement a custom annotation, wou can use the [@Named annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named) that is built-in Guice. You can then use it in your classes like this :

```
@Inject
public ReportingJob(@Priority(Priority.Level.LOW) ReportingDal dal)
{
    this.dal = dal;
}
```

**EDIT**

Or, if you are injecting via private field :

```
@Inject
@Priority(Priority.Level.LOW)
private ReportingDal dal;
```

Comment: thanks, If I am injecting via a private field (as in the question), how do I do it?

Comment: Oops, I read a little too fast. I edited my anwser to show private field injection

Comment: @ema You need to `bind` your provider in your module and `Inject` your `Provider` into the class instead of injecting `ExecutorService`

Comment: This answer doesn't have the actual example for the `@Named` annotation